# Pandas DataFrame max() and apply(max) return different values when there are missing values in the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm going through the basics of data manipulation with pandas and while working on one of the exercises I've noticed some strange behavior in the work of `max()` method when there are missing values in the data. Here is a toy example.

First create a toy data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan], 'B': [np.nan, 1]})
```

It is a 2x2 DataFrame. The only difference between columns is that there is a missing value in the first row in the second column, and in the first column it is in the second row.

```
    A   B
0   1.0 NaN
1   NaN 1.0
```

Now I try to find maximum value in each column in different ways

1. Applying `DataFrame.max()` method.

   ```
   df.max()
   ```

   It gives the results I've expected to get

   ```
   A    1.0
   B    1.0
   dtype: float64
   ```
2. Using `DataFrame.apply()` method and using `max` as argument to this method

   ```
   df.apply(max)
   ```

   The result is

   ```
   A    1.0
   B    NaN
   dtype: float64
   ```

   What is unexpected here is that maximum of column B is reported to be `NaN`. I assume that the cause is the `NaN` value in the first row.
3. Using `DataFrame.apply()` method and using `'max'` as argument to this method

   ```
   df.apply('max')
   ```

   Here the results are expected.

   ```
   A    1.0
   B    1.0
   dtype: float64
   ```

Why the result of second approach is different from the other two?